# Command Line Tools is not installing correctly on Mavericks

Tags: xcode, command-line, clang, osx-mavericks, homebrew

I've upgraded Xcode to the latest 5.1
Installed Command Line Tools via xcode-select --install
Homebrew tells me "A newer Command Line Tools release is available"

brew --config:

Xcode: 5.1
CLT: 5.1.0.0.1.1393561416
LLVM-GCC: build 2336
Clang: 3.1 build 318

Checking my clang executable:

$ /usr/bin/clang --version
Apple clang version 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.58) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)

$ /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)

So it appears Command Line Tools didn't install clang (and perhaps other executables) into /usr/bin? I checked my other laptop (w/ Mavericks), and /usr/bin/clang is version 5.1.

So I'm guessing this is the problem? I've tried to reinstall Command Line Tools as sudo, but now it won't let me install again (says software isn't currently available).

Can anyone help me with this? I've spent hours on it now, but can't find a solution.

Thanks

Comment: I am in the same boat. I'll let you know if I figure anything out.

Comment: FYI, I ended up re-imaging. The image came from my IT department, and I think there was a step added in there that caused this.